# Sketch the phase portrait of the linear dynamical system $\dot{x} = −x + 2y$, $\dot{y} = 2x − 4y$

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

Sketch the phase portrait of the linear dynamical system
$\dot{x} = −x + 2y$
$\dot{y} = 2x − 4y$

In this case i found the eignevalues to be $\lambda_1 = 0 , \lambda_2 = -5$ so $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 0$. What do i do in this case? Its different from all the questions i had before since i don't know how to classify the equilibrium point when $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 0$.

Comment: Hint: Try sketching a few vectors by hand to give you a clue as to what’s going on. Maybe think about what happens along the eigenspace for $\lambda_1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This linear dynamical system belongs to the case of 'marginal stability' as it has eigenvalues $\lambda = 0$, $\lambda = -5$. MATLAB gave general solutions for $x(t)$, $y(t)$ in terms of $e^{0 t} = 1, e^{-5 t}$ that correspond to the two eigenvalues $\lambda = 0$, $\lambda = -5$. To give some intuition about the behaviour of the solutions, I plotted the time signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ corresponding to the initial condition $x(0) = 1$, $y(0) = 1$. It can be noted that the steady-state behavior of the solutions is that they approach some constant value as $t \rightarrow \infty$. This is a typical response for a marginally stable system.

[[image: Time-Responses for <span class=]$x(0) = 1, y(0) = 1$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBkke.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Finding general solution in form $x=A_1\exp{\lambda_1 t}+A_2\exp{\lambda_2 t}$, $y=B_1\exp{\lambda_1 t}+B_2\exp{\lambda_2 t}$, one can find $A_1=2B_1$, $B_2=-2A_2$. Let mark $B_1=a$, $A_2=b$. Then general solution is $x=2a+b\exp{-5t}$, $y=a-2b\exp{-5t}$. Then $2x+y={\rm const}$ and trajectories are parallel lines corresponding this equation.

Note that points $x_0=2y_0$ are stationary points.

The only remaining part is to determine direction of trajectories for initial points above and below stationary points. If $x_0 > 2y_0$, then $\dot{x}|_{x_0,y_0} < 0$, $\dot{y}|_{x_0,y_0} > 0$, then $x$ is decreasing and $y$ is increasing so difference $x-2y$ is decreasing, that's why trajectory are directed to stationary points line. So stationary points are stable equilibrium points.

[image: phase portrait]

The arrow length doesn't mean anything here.